# xtext scope code generation dependant on different file

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I have two grammars **A** and **B** and two files **a** and **b** (using grammars **A** and **B** respectively). The file **a** specify variables names, **b** specify the filename of **a**.

In **b** using the the file **a**  want to:

- reference variables defined in **a**
- during code generation of **b** I want to include the contents of the file created generated for **a**.

How can this be done in xtext?

**Update 1**

Example grammar **B**

```
Model:
    ref_model=RefModel
    ref_vars+=[Vars]+
;

RefModel:
    'reference' 'file' name=ID
;
```

Where `RefModel` define where the file **a** can be located and `Vars` are defined in **a**.

Comment: how shall the file name be referenced? relative / absolute / project relative ..... ? you could e.g. give the model root of a the name of its file (iqualifiednameprovider) and reference it from b ref=[RootOfA|TerminalOrDataTypeRuleThatCanParseTheName] e.g. ref=[RootOfA|STRING]

Comment: The idea now is to have the files in fixed directories, given a file name the file can be found. |The example I find of `iqualifiednameprovider` work with one model and not two. How does valid data look when parsed by [RootOfA|STRING]?

Comment: It looks like "xxxx.yyyy" you could use FileName: ID "." ID; as well ( ref=[RootOfA|FileName]

Answer (score 1):

In the past we used to use importURI for that, but you can do that through scoping on your own also.

If you for instance want to use the simple name of the file, you should make the name in B a reference to the root element of A.

```
Model:
    ref_model=RefModel
    ref_vars+=[Vars]+
;

RefModel:
    'reference' 'file' name=[ModelA]
;
```

Then you need to index the root element of A models using the simple file name of the resource URI.

Comment: Where is ModelA defined? PS I got it working using importURI and looking at http://blog.efftinge.de/2009/01/xtext-scopes-and-emf-index.html

Comment: But if I have two files of grammar A Vars of both files are visible in B. How can only Vars of the file specified by importURI be made visible?

Comment: The work flow also contain fragment = scoping.ImportNamespacesScopingFragment2 auto-inject {}

Comment: I create two DLS's in different projects. When I compile **B**, I get the error `The path '/tuks.sofl/model/generated/MyDsl.genmodel' is unmapped` What do I miss?